# How to turn data with pivot?

Tags: sql-server, pivot

Data:

| CASEID | VISITDATE | QUESTION | ANSWER | COMEFROM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-02 | Q1 | 1 | H |
| 1 | 2021-01-02 | Q2 | 2 | O |
| 1 | 2021-01-02 | Q3 | 3 | B |
| 1 | 2021-01-08 | Q1 | 4 | H |
| 1 | 2021-01-08 | Q2 | 5 | O |
| 1 | 2021-01-08 | Q3 | 6 | B |

Expected result:

| CASEID | VISITDATE | Q1 | Q2 | Q3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-02 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 2021-01-08 | 4 | 5 | 6 |

My code:

```sql
SELECT CaseID, Visitdate, [Q1], [Q2], [Q3]

from

(
 select CaseID, Visitdate, Question, ANSWER, COMEFROM

 from DATA
          ) as v

pivot

(
 MAX(ANSWER) 
    
 FOR Question IN ([Q1], [Q2], [Q3])
                                    ) as p
```

OUTPUT:

| CASEID | VISITDATE | Q1 | Q2 | Q3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-02 | 1 | null | null |
| 1 | 2021-01-02 | null | 2 | null |
| 1 | 2021-01-02 | null | null | 3 |
| 1 | 2021-01-08 | 4 | null | null |
| 1 | 2021-01-08 | null | 5 | null |
| 1 | 2021-01-08 | null | null | 6 |

Comment: Please don't use all capitals, it is the internet equivalent of shouting, which is pretty rude to do when you want help.

Comment: The statement is correct. What is the problem with it?

Comment: I'm sorry, output like up.

Comment: I can't select column [comefrom], I solve the problem, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below PIVOT code. When you do pivot , the columns not in the pivot are by default applied grouping.

```sql
declare @table table(CaseId int,    VisitDate   date, Question char(2), Answer int)

insert into @table values
(1  ,'2021-01-02','Q1',1)
,(1 ,'2021-01-02','Q2',2)
,(1 ,'2021-01-02','Q3',3)
,(1 ,'2021-01-08','Q1',4)
,(1 ,'2021-01-08','Q2',5)
,(1 ,'2021-01-08','Q3',6)

SELECT * FROM @table
PIVOT
(
MAX(Answer) FOR Question in ([Q1],[Q2],[Q3])
) as pvt
```

| CaseId | VisitDate | Q1 | Q2 | Q3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-02 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 2021-01-08 | 4 | 5 | 6 |